# Generate all combinations from two data-sets

Tags: data-structures

I have a large number of expressions which I am trying to solve.

- List 1 contains formulas like `A = B + C`.
- List 2 contains additional equations for those variables, like `C = D*3`, `C = B/2`, `B = D*50`, etc.
- List 3 contains values for those variables B, D, etc.

I then need to compute all possible results for the List 1 formulas when expanding the formula by using different equations from List 2. Since these lists are large, the number of possible combinations can be huge!

I planning to break down the problem as follows:

1. For each expression in *List-1* look up all possible values for each variable in *List-2* and generate all possible expression as *List-4*. *List-4* can be huge, maybe in GB or TB!
2. Create a tree for each expression from first generated list
   Find the each variable values in *List-3*.
3. Replace constant in the expression to get the result.

Step 1 and 3 are the core problems which needs lot of memory and CPU, any guidance would be highly appreciated.

**Example:**

- List1 (Expressions): `A = x + y`, `y = u + v`
- List2 (extensions): `v = 20 + u`, `v = 30*u`
- List3 (constant values): `x = 20`, `u = 10`

Expanding with `v = 20 + u`:
`A = x + y`, `y = u + 20 + u`, `x = 20`, `u = 10`
=> y = 40, A = 60

Expanding with `v = 30*u`:
`A = x + y`, `y = u + 30*u`, `x = 20`, `u = 10`
=> y = 310, A = 330

Comment: please don't cross-post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47566167/computing-possible-formulas-expressions-from-input-data-set

Comment: It's not clear to me the relationship between List-1, List-2, and List-3.  Is List-1 and List-2 one to one or many to one?  Same question for List2 and List3.

Comment: For me it's not clear either. Am I correctly assuming that list 2 just contains variable names, that list 3 contains tuples of values for he variables in list 2, and that expressions in list 1 are considered independent from each other ?

Comment: What's the difference between:  "formulas" in list 1 written as assignments (or equalities?) involving variables -- vs. -- "values" written in list 2, also as assignments (or equalities?) involving variables?

Comment: Also we need to be clear on when/whether the elements in the various lists (not to mention all the lists as a whole) are taken in conjunction or disjunction.